# Sharing router props to components that are not wrapped in Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My route looks like this: (Main.js)

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route name="login" exact path="/login" component={LoginPass} />
      <Route name="loginWithTripId" exact path="/login/:tripid" component={LoginPass} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/trips/:tripid" component={App} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

and in my App render method: (App.js)

```
render() {
    const { classes, ...other } = this.props;
    return (
  <div className={classes.root}>
    <Appbar
    />

    <LeftDrawer
    />

    <Switch>
      <Route
        path={'/trips/dashboard'}
        render={props => (
          <Dashboard
            {...other}
            {...props}
          />
        )}
      />
      <Route
        path={'/trips/:tripid/itinerary'}
        render={props => (
          <Itinerary
            {...other}
            {...props}
          />
        )}
      />
      <Route render={() => <Redirect to={'/trips/dashboard'} />} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);
}
```

​
How do I share the router props passed in Dashboard and Itinerary without saving it in the App local state? I've tried using withRouter inside LeftDrawer and Appbar but it has the router props of its parent (Main.js). I get match.path="/trip/:tripid" instead of either "trip/:tripid/itinerary" or "trip/dashboard".

​
For context, I need to render certain elements in my appbar/leftdrawer components depending on the URL and I'd like to match using the match.path props being passed into Itinerary and Dashboard Components. For example, if I'm in the route '/trip/dashboard', the Dashboard gets loaded. So the appbar needs to have an ADD button to add trips. This button isn't present in the appbar in the Itinerary View.  In the past, I've had LeftDraewr and Appbar inside Dashboard and Itinerary Components, but I moved it up one level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want the router props in AppBar (which is rendered on all pages) then you can just wrap it in a route that matches every path:

```
<Route path="*" component={AppBar}/>
```

With the '*' path it will render on every page just as it does now, and being wrapped in the `<Route/>` then it should have the router props available.